# How do I properly use a selected subtable in a formula?

Tags: mysql, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have a table, TASKS.OPENEDDATE, and a month (from the user) for which I create a subtable.

I have two functions, {@FirstDayOfReportingMonth} and {@LastDayOfReportingMonth}, which return a DateTime. I have another function, {@openedDatesInRange}, which simply returns the subtable that is between those two values.

@openedDatesInRange

```
 {TASKS.OPENEDDATE} in {@FirstDayOfReportingMonth} to {@LastDayOfReportingMonth}
```

I use @openedDatesInRange as a table in a DateDiff like so:

```
 DateDiff ("d",{@openedDatesInRange} ,{@closedDatesInRange} )
```

which gives the error "A date is required here." I'm very new to Crystal, so I think what's happening is that @openedDatesInRange isn't actually a table of DateTimes, as I though it was. Can someone explain how best to implement a table selection which can then be used in a formula?

My understanding is that the function I've written will:

1. Take the Openeddate table
2. Grab records that fall within @FirstDay and @LastDay
3. Return the subtable of records.

This subtable will then be used with DateDiff to create another table, in memory, of DateDiffs, which I will then select from again for averaging based on Tasks.Priority (which is another table I haven't mentioned until now).

Comment: Haaaa lot of tables.. can you split and explain in which formula you got the error.. start debuggimg from formula and acheive the result next

Comment: @Siva, the error comes when I try to save the function:

     `DateDiff ("d",{@openedDatesInRange} ,{@closedDatesInRange} )`

It highlights {@openedDatesInRange} and tells me that it's not a date.

Comment: it means you are trying to take difference of dates which are not dates in itself. So you need to first convert those into dates and try `Datediff`